# Scripts not running in contribution pages

Tags: civicontribute, joomla, javascript

Contribution page loads slowly and is missing the field for "total amount" . Viewing in console indicates that all scripts fail to load because the path references source path of https://xxxURL.xxx/**components/com_civicrm/civicrm**/bower_components/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js?r=GcFU5”.
All scripts for the page fail. The problem is obviously that the path should be: **administrator/components/com_civicrm/civicrm/etc.**

I've looked everywhere I can think of but don't see where that path variable is set. Civicrm.settings.php file is set correctly.

Any thoughts?
[image]

Answer (score 1):

I couldn't find it as well, so what i did is in css of the template, I hid the label. This was my workaround.
.crm-section section-pricesetTotal  {
color: #ffffff;
font-size: 0px;
}

You may want to clean up your profile display in the template as well, have the labels and fields on the same line.